# CSS -div expands for multi line text vs single line text

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

I'm trying to show a text in a border div located in absolute location inside another div.

Option 1 with  **width:auto;** - fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c21kt6r4/
The problem is that the left side box expands too much.

[image]

Option 2 - with  **width:min-content;** fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay159rw6/2/
The problem is that the right side box text wraps.

[image]

What is the clean way to wrap text in div and show a correct border in both multi and single line texts?

For reference the html is :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="item" style="left:0;">
      <label>SHAMPOO & CONDITIONER</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="left:165px;">
      <label>WHAT EVER</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.main{
 position:relative;
 border:solid black 1px;
 width:400px;
 height:400px; 
}
.item{
  border:solid blue 1px;
  width:160px;
  height:150px;
  position: absolute;
}
.item label{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5%;
  left:5%;
  border:solid red 1px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
  width:min-content;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css alone

Comment: If to do this dynamically you need script, as an element doesn't know when its content needs/will wrap.

Comment: A CSS workaround could be to give the element a `min-width` so it won't wrap to small text content.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps.

1) You need to warp the label inside a div and then give it `position:absolute`. Also you need to use `right:5%` to give spacing on both lefr-right sides. We're wrapping into a div because we want **position relative** to div we're applying **table cell** property.

2) You need to `display: table-cell;` your label tag `.item label`

3) Give `word-break: break-all;` your label tag `.item label` so word can take whole space

Here is the working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o5dgzn0c/

[Demo image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKeJh.png)

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad A - but I need the word wrapping to work in words level.

Comment: In word level? Can you explain it further?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you going with `max-width` here, because it will limit max width of the item element to some value and keep possibility to include `width:auto` feature width for all elements less than it, something like:

```
.item label{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5%;
  left:5%;
  border:solid red 1px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100px;
}
```

However, I would go with JS approach on this, as you have no idea what text might appear.

Comment: Thanks, @MS90  - not ideal but looks like the best solution so far...
How would you solve it with js in an elegant way?